# Android - cooperation between SQLite, Alarm Receiver and Async Task

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I'm developing a simple Android App which uses SQLite connection. When I run it it performs an Async Task which reads all records from the SQLite and shows them in App as a list:

```
public class ReadData extends AsyncTask< Void, Void, String >
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground( Void... arg0 ) 
    {
        Database oDatabase = new Database( );
        SQLiteDatabase myDB = oDatabase.getWritableDatabase( );
        Cursor cursor = myDB.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM `items` ORDER BY `id`", null );

        if( cursor != null )
        {
            while( cursor.moveToNext( ) )
            {
                MainActivity.items.add( new DataItem( Database.getIntegerIndex( cursor, "test a" ), Database.getIntegerIndex( cursor, "test b" ), Database.getIntegerIndex( cursor, "test c" ), Database.getIntegerIndex( cursor, "test d" ) ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I click the button "add" an Alarm Receiver runs another Async Task after 30 seconds and it does few database inserts:

```
public class InsertData extends AsyncTask< Void, Void, String >
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground( Void... arg0 ) 
    {
        Database oDatabase = new Database( );
        SQLiteDatabase myDB = oDatabase.getWritableDatabase( );
        ContentValues newTodoValues = new ContentValues( );

        int iTestA = new Random( ).nextInt( 100 );
        int iTestB = new Random( ).nextInt( 100 );
        int iTestC = new Random( ).nextInt( 100 );
        int iTestD = new Random( ).nextInt( 100 );

        newTodoValues.put( "test a", iTestA );
        newTodoValues.put( "test b", iTestB );
        newTodoValues.put( "test c", iTestC );
        newTodoValues.put( "test d", iTestD );

        myDB.insert( "items", null, newTodoValues );

        boolean bIsRunning = false;
        String[ ] tokens = Tools.getBase( ).getApplicationContext( ).getPackageName( ).split( "\\." );

        if( tokens.length >= 3 && tokens[ 0 ].equals( "kibbo" ) && tokens[ 1 ].equals( "soft" ) && tokens[ 2 ].equals( "app" ) )
            bIsRunning = Tools.getBase( ).getApplicationContext( ).getPackageName( ).equalsIgnoreCase( ( ( ActivityManager )Tools.getBase( ).getApplicationContext( ).getSystemService( Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE ) ).getRunningTasks( 1 ).get( 0 ).topActivity.getPackageName( ) );

        if( bIsRunning && Tools.base.getEngine( ) != null )
            MainActivity.items.add( new DataItem( newTodoValues.getAsInteger( "test a" ), newTodoValues.getAsInteger( "test b" ), newTodoValues.getAsInteger( "test c" ), newTodoValues.getAsInteger( "test d" ) ) );
    }
}
```

When I click "add" button and leave App, Alarm Receiver will still perform Async Task and SQL inserts after 30 seconds. Is it safe? I mean could something happen when I run my app perfectly in the middle of Async Task's SQL inserts? Is it possible something wrong might happen?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say basing on the code you've posted. If the `AsyncTask`s are inside **foregrounded** `Service`/s then nothing wrong should happen, but otherwise the `AsyncTask` may be killed by the OS (after user leave the app) if a low memory condition occours.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's save, as long as no other thread try to write into the same database with different connection.

Because trying to take a write lock for database by different connection in a different thread will generate a run-time exception.

To solve this you can implement a singleton database connection and all access to database will serialized by default.